# Convert a Blob into an Appwrite InputFile with dart

Tags: dart, blob, appwrite

my question might seem simple but I cannot come up with a solution so I need some community help.

I want to build an Appwrite Dart function to safe a `Blob` in the Appwrite Storage system. Therfore I need to create an `InputFile` which has the method `InputFile.fromBytes(bytes, filename)` where bytes needs to be a `List<int>`. But how can I convert the blob into a `List<int>`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you please provide some more context around what your code is and what you have since Blob is an HTML-specific class and not really available in an Appwrite Dart Function?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the `readAsBytes()` method of the `File` class in dart to get achieve what you need.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  String filePath = 'path/to/your/file.txt';

  final file = File(filePath);
  if (!file.existsSync()) {
    print('File does not exist at the specified path');
    return;
  }
  final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();

  final inputFile = InputFile.fromBytes(
    bytes: bytes,
    filename: 'file.txt',
  );
}
```